# How to use a same DB with 2 different React applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, pouchdb

I have to make an offline application that sync with another online app when it can.

I developed **the offline app** using PouchDB. I create this app thanks to the github repo [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). This app is running at localhost:3000. In this app, I create and manage a little DB named "patientDB".

I manage the db with the classical put method like we can see in the documentation:

```
var db = new PouchDB('patientDB')
db.put({
_id: 'dave@gmail.com',
name: 'David',
age: 69
});
```

With the development tool for chrome given by PouchDB, I can see that the DB is working like I want (the documents are created):

[image: Db overview]

**The other application** is another React application with a node server. During the development, this app is running at localhost:8080.
In this app I try to fetch all the docs contained in the "patientDB" with the following code:

```
const db = new PouchDB('patientDB', { skip_setup: true });
    db.info()
    .then(() => {
    console.log("DBFOUND")
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true})
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log("RESULT" , result)
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log("NOPE")
      console.log(err);
    });
    })
```

**My problem** is that I can't get the "patientDB" created with the offline app in the online app. When I do a `var db = new PouchDB ('patientDB')` it create a new and empty db because it can't find a db which is already present.

I use google chrome to run all my application so I thought that the dbs could be shared.

However I did  little and very simple tests with two html files:

**First.html** which initialize a new db with a doc
**Second.html** which read the db create in First.html
In this case, I can fetch the doc created with First.html in Second.hmtl even if the are two separated "website".

I think that the application which run at a localhost are like isolated of the rest of the application even if, like I said before, I use the same browser for all my applications...

I don't know what to do or I don't know if it's even possible to do what I want to do. If someone has an idea for me, I would be pleased.

---

**EDIT**

I can see why my DBs are not shared:
When I look at all my local DBs after running an html file I can see the following thing : 
[image: local db]

As we can see, the DBs come from the files `_pouch_DB_NAME - file://`

When I check my DB from the application running localy (localhost), I can see this :
[image: db from localhost]

The DB don't come from file but from `localhost:8080`

If you know how I can fetch doc from a local db in an app running in a server, it could be really helpful for me!

Answer (score 1):

PouchDB is using IndexedDB in the browser, which adheres to a same-origin policy. [MDN says this:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB#concepts)

> **IndexedDB adheres to a same-origin policy.** An origin is the domain, application layer protocol, and port of a URL of the document where the script is being executed. Each origin has its own associated set of databases. Every database has a name that identifies it within an origin.

So you have to replicate your local database to a central server in order to share the data. This could be a [PouchDB Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-server) together with your node app. You can also access PouchDB Server directly from the browser:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/patientDB')
```

As an alternative, you can use CouchDB or IBM Cloudant (which is basically hosted CouchDB).