# Sync PouchDB with server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, pouchdb, offlineapps

I'm currently working for a startup which ask me to develop an offline app using pouchDB. This pouchdb is used to store the data entered by users.
The offline application works fine. Now I have to add one feature on the online app to sync the dbs. After a login, the online app have to check if data is stored in a pouchdb on the device which is connecting, and, if the check found data, the online app have to pull this data.
I have the folowing problem: the online app can't get the db stored localy on the device (even if I run the both app in the same browser).

I explain my problem in another StackOverflow post, but the formulation was not so good so I think that's a good thing to post another question.

My old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812787/how-to-use-a-same-db-with-2-different-react-applications)

I work on this problem during few days and I don't have much time until I have to finish my work, if someone know how to solve this, it could be very nice :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the lack of response is because readers are not very clear what the problem is. In your other post it sounds like you are saying if you write a new entry to the local database you cannot retrieve it again. In this question it sounds like once you have a local database entry you cannot make it replicate to the server database - is that the case?

On [the PouchDb front page](https://pouchdb.com/) is a short example of writing to a local database and then replicating it to a server. Like this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');

db.put({
  _id: 'dave@gmail.com',
  name: 'David',
  age: 69
});

db.replicate.to('http://example.com/mydb');
```

*(the example assumes the database can be updated by anyone ie no security - otherwise you need a username and password [as explained here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database))*

Does this work for you? If not can you say what happens?

Checking to see if there is data locally should be a case of seeing if your local database has any entries in it ([db.info](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#database_information) would be a start as it returns a document count). Then you could replicate the local database using the [db.replicate](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) call.

Does this help?

Comment: I think this is not the problem of TS, he is running his local offline pouchDB in a different host than his local online(the one that actually sync) pouchdb(for example localhost:3000 instead of localhost:9000). The problem with this is pouchDB stores the information based on both name + host. As otherwise you could easily run in name conflicts. So the problem is even though those two databases share the same name, the app that can connect to the internet uses a different db(but with the same name). As a result he is unable to sync the data of his offline db.